# Cannot open database "AppFabricMonitoringDB" requested by the login

Tags: sql-server, appfabric

I keep getting an error running AppFabric monitoring:

> Unable to open database connection for the following application(s)
>   .... Received exception. Message: Cannot
>   open database "AppFabricMonitoringDB" requested by the login. The
>   login failed. Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'..

I have created the database added the login. The web services run in an application pool with identity local system. The database is hosted by sql server 2008R.

I ran the AppFabric configuration tool. The sql agent is running.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you have a mismatched password? Did you try to login to the same database with the same credentials, say, using SSMS?

Comment: I installed AppFabric 'the default way'. As far as I know, passwords are not an issue as the app bool uses a local built in identity, so it uses windows authentication. I do not want to run the AppFabric on a self made account, as I want to use the setup on different deployment machines. Thus, my question remains, how can I grant access to NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM?

Comment: If so, your question was unclear. The title seems to ask what causes this error message.
In order to grant access to an SQL account you need to have admin rights to the server. I suppose Google can help you better than me in finding out exactly where those definitions are located in your specific DB.

Comment: I have heard of Google, and in fact I did try to find the answer to my problem first by extensive searching. I usually do that before posting a question on stackoverflow. Furthermore, if you read more than the title, is the question still unclear?, if so, I will try and make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The trick that, in the end, did it was:

> If you want to read the AppFabric Monitoring Database from a Web
>   Application your web app will have to have permission to login.
>
> If you try to run a web app that does not have permission you will
>   likely see this
>
> Cannot open database "AppFabricMonitoringDB" requested by the login.
>   The login failed.  Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'.
>
> You have two choices.
>
> Run the Web Application in an AppPool using an identity that has
>   permission to login Grant permissions to the DefaultAppPool identity
>   Rather than directly granting logins via SQL, Windows Server AppFabric
>   has security groups that you can use.

I changed the application pool identity to: ApplicationPoolIdentity.